# How to develop multiple Google Cloud Functions in different languages and are them a good choice to implement a facial recognition system?

Tags: javascript, python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

My question is really short... Actually, I have multiples cloud functions on my project developed in Node.js, but I want to create a new one in Python to run the OpenCV library.

Is it possible to combine two languages for different cloud functions in the same project (and in the same region)?

In my package.json I have this:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
```

And if not, do you think I should do the facial recognition using TensorFlow.js (so I use the same language for all functions)? Also, I am not sure if it is good to run 'computing code' on Cloud Functions, so I would be very grateful if someone with more experience with cloud computing guides me.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create multiple independent functions in your project, they can run any of the supported [runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec) and they can run in any [supported region](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations).

To properly answer your question, you need to ask yourself how resource intensive the facial recognition workloads are, usually these workloads make use of GPUs and sometimes TPUs. Cloud Functions is intended for short running jobs, here are some [examples use cases](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview#use_cases), the max timeout for a Cloud Function is 9 minutes and the limits for Cloud Functions can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits). If your workloads can run on top of said limitations, then I would keep using Cloud Functions.

However, if you find that Cloud Functions are hindering the ability to perform your jobs, then I would instead take a look at the [Vision AI](https://cloud.google.com/vision) products that GCP offers, they are more specific around image recognition. If you want to build your own model then Tensorflow would be a better option.